# How do I make my own title slide layour in slide master and make it stick?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I'm creating my own theme in Powerpoint 2016 on Windows 10. I have a couple of slide layouts, including a title slide layout. However, when I save this theme and then create a new slide deck using it, it turns out Powerpoint added a new layour called "Title Slide" to it and used this one instead of the one I created. Even if I have a layout called "Title slide", Powerpoint tends to ignore it and creates e.g. "1_Title slide" layout and uses this one.

How can I make my title layout stick as **the title slide**?

Comment: Please describe exactly how you're creating a new title slide. Usually you get 1_LayoutName layouts when you copy/paste a slide from one presentation to another and the layout of the pasted slide doesn't exactly match the same-named layout in the presentation you're pasting it into.

Comment: I just create a new presentation using that theme. One slide gets created, it's a title slide, and it looks like a default "new slide" layout, not my custom "Title Slide" layout.

Comment: Is your custom Title Slide layout the first layout in the list, just below the slide master, when you do View | Slide Master?

Comment: Yes it is. And instead, a new slide layout gets created at the end of all layouts, and that one is used as the title slide.

Comment: It might help to post a video of this process and/or a link to the theme.